# Query all the active employees in one table and see if they have data in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to query between two tables where I can get all the active employees from one table and get all the employees from the form if they signed it from another table.

```
Example:

Table 1                                       Table 2
select * from tblEmpl                         select * from tblSign 


select tblSign.sigdate,tblSign.sigtime,tblSign.sigact,tblSign.esignature,tblEmpl.fname,tblEmpl.lname,tblEmpl.location,tblEmpl.estatus,tblLocs.unit,tblLocs.descript,TblLocs.addr1,tblLocs.city,tblLocs.state,tblLocs.zip from tblSign left join tblEmpl on tblSign.eight_id = tblEmpl.eight_id left join tblLocs on tblEmpl.location=tblLocs.location where tblSign.formid='9648' and tblSign.sigact <> 'O' and tblEmpl.estatus='A' and tblEmpl.location='013' and tblSign.sigdate>='2022-11-01' order by tblSign.sigdate asc;
```

I used this query but it only get all the active employees that signed the form not all the active employees and extra column if they signed.

```
sigdate                    sigtime      sigact  fname  lname      
2022-11-01 00:00:00      3:16:35 PM      A      EMORY CORTEZ
```

Comment: I strongly recommend you start using line breaks and white space; that query is *far* too long to be on a single line and makes it *very* difficult to be read.

Comment: This [recent blog](https://sqlblog.org/2022/11/08/t-sql-tuesday-156-production-code) I feel may be worth reading.

Comment: The apostrophes for number type field parameters are not needed but don't seem to hurt.

Comment: If the OP's columns like `sigact` are actually a `varchar` then the single quotes (`'`) are actually a *must* @June7; I would assume they are if I saw the OP's query and didn't have access to the definition of the table(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current query is left joining from tblSign to tblEmpl - i.e. get all records from tblSign and matching records from tblEmpl, from the sounds of your question you actually want to invert that (i.e. get all tblEmpl records matching a certain criteria and any matching records from tblSign). You also have filters in your WHERE clause filtering the set on specific criteria from tblSign - given that you won't have matching tblSign records for every result from tblEmpl, those filters will essentially trim the final resultset down to only records with those values in tblSign.

To address, invert your join condition and push the tblSign filters up into your join condition, something like this:

```
SELECT tblSign.sigdate,
       tblSign.sigtime,
       tblSign.sigact,
       tblSign.esignature,
       tblEmpl.fname,
       tblEmpl.lname,
       tblEmpl.location,
       tblEmpl.estatus,
       tblLocs.unit,
       tblLocs.descript,
       TblLocs.addr1,
       tblLocs.city,
       tblLocs.state,
       tblLocs.zip
FROM tblEmpl
LEFT JOIN tblSign
ON tblSign.eight_id = tblEmpl.eight_id
    AND tblSign.formid = '9648'
    AND tblSign.sigact <> 'O'
    AND tblSign.sigdate >= '2022-11-01'
LEFT JOIN tblLocs
ON tblEmpl.location = tblLocs.location
WHERE tblEmpl.estatus = 'A'
    AND tblEmpl.location = '013'
ORDER BY
    tblSign.sigdate ASC;
```

Some other things to note:

- Assuming you have tblEmpl records that don't have matches in tblSign, your order by clause will sort NULLs together. If that's what you want, you're good - if you want to treat them differently, you'll need to adapt your ORDER BY to do so (i.e. perhaps with a coalesce or similar)
- If you have multiple records in tblSign for given employees, you'll get multiple records fot the same tblEmpl record in the resultset

Comment: Is there a way where I can not get the most recent records besides all the multiple records.

Comment: Can you help me with something?

Comment: @TimmyTurn123 I can't do much on this question as it's closed, but I'm happy to try and help if I can, what with?

Comment: How would I fix this with your query If you have multiple records in tblSign for given employees, you'll get multiple records fot the same tblEmpl record in the resultset?